# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form

Does the following series have a closed form ?

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Motivation :

The original exercise is

> Compute $\int_{1}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \exp(-x\cdot \sqrt{n})dx$

I switched sums and integral using my course. But I am stuck to compute the series.

Comment: do you absolutely need a closed form? The inner sum is easily approximated with the integral using Euler-Maclaurin formula, and then integration is trivial

Comment: @Alex I just checked Euler-Maclaurin. It converges slowly. [Abel-Plana Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Plana_formula) leads to an horrendous integral.

Comment: hmmm I didn't check, sorry, I guess it was a knee-jerk reaction. What I meant you could first approximate the sum with an integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x \sqrt{n}}dn$ to get something like $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and then integrate wrt $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does the following series have a closed form ?*

If it does, then it's not known. When the exponent itself is a power of the variable, the only known closed forms are for when *its* exponent is $1$ or $2$; e.g., $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2}=\frac{\sqrt[4]\pi}{\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac34\bigg)}$ , to give a less trivial example. However, the definite integral associated with our series does have a rather nice closed form, namely $~\displaystyle\int\frac{e^{-\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}dx=2\int e^{-t}~dt=-2e^{-t}=-2e^{-\sqrt x}$. When computed over $(1,\infty)$, it yields $\dfrac2e$ as a result. Indeed, the numerical value of our series is slightly bigger than that, around $1$.

Comment: For your series, do you have any reference (proof) ?

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n^2}=\theta_3(0,a)$ is a [Jacobi $\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). I've come across some of them whilst going through [Ramanujan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) letters and notebooks.